# PHP: OpCache Preloading is triggered everytime and stops other tasks

Tags: php, php-7.4, php-8

I'm using two docker-compose services, nginx and php-fpm. On the php-fpm I've mounted the php.ini which contains the `opcache.preload*` settings like this:

```
opcache.preload_user = www-data
opcache.preload = /var/www/html/bootstrap/preload.php
```

Now I expected this to be called once to preload everything and that's it, but instead it gets triggered every time I run a php related task like composer or phpunit AND the other tasks never get run. I have confirmed that - for some reason - the preloading is really expected to be called on every server request, but I don't understand why it interrupts and stops other calls like `composer require`. I printed out the output of my preload to be sure it really is the culprit, and since it runs every time but nothing else, I suspect it. Has anyone else done this / solved it? Or do I need to disable `opcache.preload*` after the first startup?

Comment: I got a working, but IMO bad solution: I log the preloaded files in a preload.txt and if this file exists, I do an early return. It works (after the first request), but I'm not convinced that this is how it should be.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is that the preload is running for _command-line_ PHP scripts, where it's not really useful. Depending on how the OS is configured, you might be able to use a different php.ini file for CLI vs FPM.